# D: How to get free disk space on media/partition?

Tags: size, d, partition

I need to get total and free size on partition. How I can get it with D?
Which functions should I use for it?

Comment: Figure out how to do it in C, then call that function from D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a Posix system (includes Linux, but typically not Windows), you can use the `statvfs` C function, which is available in D via `import core.sys.posix.sys.statvfs;`.

Generally speaking, any Posix C function is in `import core.sys.posix.something` where `something` is the same as the C `#cinlude` name just with `/` swapped out for `.`.

Anyway, this little program will print out some info about teh filesystem mounted at `"/"`:

```
import core.sys.posix.sys.statvfs;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
        statvfs_t buf;

        if(statvfs("/", &buf))
                throw new Exception("failed");

        writeln(buf.f_bfree * buf.f_bsize, " free bytes");
        writeln(buf.f_blocks * buf.f_bsize, " total size in bytes");

        writeln((buf.f_bfree * buf.f_bsize) / 1024, " free KB");
        writeln((buf.f_blocks * buf.f_bsize) / 1024, " total size in KB");

        writeln(100 - (buf.f_bfree * 100 / buf.f_blocks), "% used");
}
```

It is a pretty easy function call. On Windows, it is different, but similarly easy:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

just call that function. I can write up an example for that too if you need one though I didn't now because the updated Windows headers that includes it won't be included until the next D release in a couple weeks, so you'd have to `extern(Windows)` it now... but in a couple weeks you won't have to.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is operating system specific. On Linux systems, you want the [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) syscall (in C). You might need to make the glue code between C & D yourself.

Comment: Indeed, the prototypes aren't in the D runtime but it is really easy to do yourself: you can basically just copy/paste it from the man page into your D file in an `extern(C)` block.

Comment: I have never did it. Also I do not know C. Could you show me example of original code, wrapped `extern(C)` and example of it's calling.

Comment: No, I don't know enough D to help you quickly. It should be simple, and well documented

Comment: Well, the druntime does have statvfs which is the posix version of the same thing so... I'll write an example with hat.